# Animating while resizing a view

Tags: ios

I have a view containing many bubbles of various sizes. I am trying to create an animation that will zoom into a bubble, making it the same size every time, and center it in my view. This would cause all the bubbles to zoom until the bubble in question is the right size. The bubbles should all maintain the same ratio throughout the process so that if one bubble moves, all the others move the same amount and in the same direction. If one grows, they all grow in proportion.

I have gotten as far as creating the animation to center the bubble and all the other bubbles move proportionally. The problems arise when I try to make the bubbles grow. Once I add the line bellow which does successfully make the bubbles grow in proportion, the code to move the bubble to center the bubbles no longer moves the bubble to the right point. I cannot figure out how to make the bubble both grow and move to the right position.

To move the bubbles (Needs to be 22p from the top and centered horizontally, and 64p by 64p in size), this successfully moves the bubbles to the right position without growing them to the correct size:

```
float distanceFromTop = 22 - bubble.frame.origin.y;
float distanceFromLeft = self.frame.size.width / 2 - bubble.center.x;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.currentKarmaView.frame = CGRectMake(distanceFromLeft, distanceFromTop, self.currentKarmaView.frame.size.width, self.currentKarmaView.frame.size.height);
}];
```

To make the bubbles grow, I added the following line, which should make the bubbles grow and move them to the right position. With growth added, the bubbles still move, just not to the right position.

```
float distanceFromTop = 22 - bubble.frame.origin.y;
float distanceFromLeft = self.frame.size.width / 2 - bubble.center.x;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.currentKarmaView.frame = CGRectMake(distanceFromLeft, distanceFromTop, self.currentKarmaView.frame.size.width, self.currentKarmaView.frame.size.height);
    self.currentKarmaView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
}];
```

I have tried many many variations of this, but cannot get the growth and positioning to work in unison. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: maybe try making it bigger when setting the frame and leave out setting the transform(`self.currentKarmaView.transform`)

Comment: The problem is that the subviews aren't proportional. No matter how big I make the frame, the subviews will remain the same size. (CurrentKarmaView has bubbles added as subviews) @NewEngland

Comment: So show the code that you are using to try to change the subviews size

Comment: Transforming the view with `CGAffineTransformScale` accomplishes the resizing. The problem with resizing them individually is that I need them to stay in proportion with is difficult to accomplish individually. @NewEngland

Comment: This is the second line in the animation block in the second code snippet.